# Makefile doesn't find libs

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, linker-errors

I'm trying to write Makefile for my project. 
Here is the file structure:

[image]

Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -ISDL2/include -std=c++11
LXXFLAGS = -lSDL2/lib/x86 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

main.exe: main.o BoardField.o ChessPiece.o Game.o
    g++ main.o BoardField.o ChessPiece.o Game.o -o main.exe $(LXXFLAGS) -std=c++11

main.o: main.cpp 
    g++ main.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS)

BoardField.o: BoardField.cpp 
    g++ BoardField.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

ChessPiece.o: ChessPiece.cpp 
    g++ ChessPiece.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

Game.o: Game.cpp 
    g++ Game.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS)
```

And I get these errors:

> g++ main.o BoardField.o ChessPiece.o Game.o -o main.exe -lSDL2/lib/x86
>   -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -std=c++11 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lSDL2/lib/x86
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lSDL2main
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lSDL2
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lSDL2_image

Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is related to  `g++`

Answer (score 6):

`-lSDL2/lib/x86` is incorrect. You use the lower-case `-l` option, which is used to add a *library* to link with, not a path to search for libraries.

To add a path use the upper-case `-L` option: `-LSDL2/lib/x86`